# google map district api - polygon usage

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

I want to use this map with "İlçeleri Göster" selected (top of map):
http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://election-results.googlecode.com/hg/turkey2011/gadget/turkey-results-gadget.xml?1&synd=open&w=960&h=525

You will see a polygon over Turkey map, its just what i need but i couldnt re-sample it. Can you help me?  (Sorry for non-english example but i couldnt find english version of this map.)

**Update:** i found http://code.google.com/p/election-results/source/browse/ but still couldnt re-sample.. still trying.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are the borders for the provinces, there are a few options.  At least as a last resort, you can use the tool described at http://martinove.dk/2011/03/17/polylinepolygon-tool-for-google-maps/ to generate the code.

That said, it seems to me that the project you site makes the data available as KML files in http://code.google.com/p/election-results/source/browse/#hg%2Fturkey2011%2Fshapes%2Fkml.

(If the problem isn't getting the data but rendering it, edit your question to show what you've tried and maybe someone can figure out where the problem is.)